# Hacer operaciones sobre columnas en una bucle de una Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pandas

Quiero hacer calculos sobre tres columnas de un array `values_array`.

```
def calculateAllEMA(self,values_array):
    df = pd.DataFrame(values_array, columns=['BTC', 'ETH', 'DASH'])
    for i,column in enumerate(df[column]):
        ema=[]
        for i in range(0, len(column)-24):
            EMA_yesterday = column.iloc[1+i:22+i].mean()
            k = float(2)/(22+1)
            ema.append(column.iloc[23 + i]*k+EMA_yesterday*(1-k))
        mean_exp[i] = ema[-1]
    return mean_exp
```

Pero me dice :

```
    for i,column in enumerate(df[column]):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'column' referenced before assignment
```

Y no veo donde se referencia...

Aqui esta `values_array` :

```
[(3554.05, 299.44, 198.51), (3554.05, 299.46, 198.51),
(3554.05, 299.55, 198.54), (3554.05, 299.55, 198.54),
(3554.05, 299.55, 198.54), (3554.05, 299.55, 198.51),
(3554.05, 299.44, 198.51), (3553.8, 299.64,198.49),
(3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.65, 198.49),
(3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.65, 198.49),
(3553.8, 299.64, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.65, 198.49),
(3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), 
(3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.64, 198.49), 
(3553.91, 299.55, 198.54), (3553.8, 299.64, 198.49), 
(3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.69, 198.49),
(3553.8, 299.65, 198.49), (3553.8, 299.65, 198.49)]
```

Comment: tal vez escribir column = 0 antes del for te sirva, así declaras la variable y toma el valor 0 al inicio del ciclo

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán Hmm, con esto me dice : `KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que está usando una variable que aún no ha sido asignada:

```
for i,column in enumerate(df[column]):
```

**column** en el segmento **enumerate(df[column])** no está definida.

Debería intentar con algo similar a esto:

```
def calculateAllEMA(values_array):
    df = pd.DataFrame(values_array, columns=['BTC', 'ETH', 'DASH'])
    column_by_search = "BTC" # Según el nombre de la columna en 'columns'
    for i,column in enumerate(df[column_by_search]):
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Quiero utilisar cadas ques estan en `columns` : `BTC, ETH` y `DASH`, puedo cambiar `df[column_by_search]` con columns ?

Comment: Es similar, sólo debe indicar que `column_by_search` sea una lista:
`column_by_search = ["BTC", "ETH", "DASH"]` y usarla para el código:

`column_by_search = ["BTC", "ETH", "DASH"]`

`df = pd.DataFrame(values_array, columns=columns_by_search)`

`for i,column in enumerate(df[column_by_search]):`

Comment: A mi parecer, esto funciona. Habrá alguna posibilidad de una manera más elegante ?  Que permita evitar escribir los indices `BTC,ETH,DASH` ?Ahora tengo : `mean_exp[i] = ema[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range`. Pienso que esta vacío al principio.

Comment: Plantéelo como una nueva pregunta para ayudarle de mejor manera. :)

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que necesitas, si quieres iterar cada columna, es algo como esto:

```
def calculateAllEMA(self,values_array):
    columns = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'DASH']
    df = pd.DataFrame(values_array, columns=columns)
    for i, column in enumerate(columns):
        ema=[]
        for j in range(0, len(df[column])-24):
            EMA_yesterday = df[column].iloc[1+j:22+j].mean()
            k = float(2)/(22+1)
            ema.append(df[column].iloc[23 + j]*k+EMA_yesterday*(1-k))
        mean_exp[i] = ema[-1]
    return mean_exp
```

No estoy seguro si `df[column]` es correcto ya que no conozco mucho sobre la librería, pero tiene sentido.

Ten en cuenta que en el segundo loop estoy usando `j` para no interferir con el `i` de tu primer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas tiene sus propios iteradores, si quieres iterar por columnas y a la vez recoger el índice de cada columna, se haría así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = values, columns = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'DASH'])

for idx,columna in enumerate(df):

print(idx, columna)
```

Salida:

```
0 BTC
1 ETH
2 DASH
```

Si quieres recorrer filas:

```
for fila in df.iterrows():

    print(fila)
```

Salida:

```
(0, BTC     3554.05
ETH      299.44
DASH     198.51
Name: 0, dtype: float64)
(1, BTC     3554.05
ETH      299.46
DASH     198.51
Name: 1, dtype: float64)
(2, BTC     3554.05
ETH      299.55
DASH     198.54
Name: 2, dtype: float64)

...
```

Por lo que tu función quedaría así:

```
def calculateAllEMA(self,values_array):

    df = pd.DataFrame(values_array, columns=['BTC', 'ETH', 'DASH'])


    for idx,column in enumerate(df):

        ema=[]

        for i in range(0, len(df)-24):

            EMA_yesterday = column.iloc[1+i:22+i].mean()

            k = float(2)/(22+1)

            ema.append(column.iloc[23 + i]*k+EMA_yesterday*(1-k))

        mean_exp[i] = ema[-1]

    return mean_exp
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.