# ¿Como calcular la media móvil exponencial con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas

Quiero saber como podemos calcular [la media móvil exponencial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_m%C3%B3vil#Media_m.C3.B3vil_exponencial) con Python3. Aqui esta un conjunto de datos sobre las cryptomonedas :

```
        BTC     ETH    DASH
0   3539.19  302.49  201.78
1   3539.19  302.56  201.78
2   3539.18  302.56  201.78
3   3539.18  302.56  201.78
4   3539.26  302.56  201.78
5   3539.26  302.56  201.78
6   3539.19  302.49  201.78
7   3539.26  302.54  201.78
8   3539.19  302.56  201.78
9   3539.18  302.56  201.78
10  3539.18  302.56  201.78
11  3539.26  302.56  201.78
12  3539.26  302.56  201.78
13  3539.84  302.54  201.78
14  3539.26  302.54  201.78
15  3539.84  302.54  201.78
16  3539.84  302.54  201.78
17  3539.84  302.54  201.78
18  3539.84  302.54  201.78
19  3539.50  302.54  201.78
20  3539.84  302.54  201.78
21  3539.84  302.54  201.78
22  3539.84  302.54  201.78
23  3539.84  302.54  201.78
```

Intento la funcion siguiente :

```
def calculateAllEMA(self,values_array):
    df = pd.DataFrame(values_array, columns=['BTC', 'ETH', 'DASH'])
    column_by_search = ["BTC", "ETH", "DASH"]
    for i,column in enumerate(column_by_search):
        ema=[]
        print("column")
        print(column)
        # cada de las dias que siguen la 23 para obtener EMA
        #for i in range(0, len(column)-24): ??????????
        for j in range(0, len(column)-22):
            # Agregar los precios de cierre para los primeros 22 días juntos y dividirlos por 22.
            EMA_yesterday = column.iloc[1+j:22+j].mean()
            k = float(2)/(22+1)
            # Obteniendo el primer día EMA tomando el precio de cierre del día siguiente (día 23) multiplicado por k, luego multiplique el promedio móvil del día anterior por (1-k) y agregue los dos.
            ema.append(column.iloc[23 + j]*k+EMA_yesterday*(1-k))
        print("ema")
        print(ema)
        mean_exp[i] = ema[-1]
    return mean_exp
```

Pero tengo la errora siguiente :

```
    mean_exp[j] = ema[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Porque `ema` está vacío.

La razon esta que nucna utilisamos la bucle interior porque `len(column)` vale -21 (24 - 3 ?). No esta el tamano de cada columna pero el nombre de columnas que habemos.

Comment: Marine1, revisa el valor de `column` por si no llega a ejecutar el loop, el otro problema es `mean_exp[j]`, en dónde inicializas `j`?

Comment: Marine1, en tu pregunta anterior puse mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94455/hacer-operaciones-sobre-columnas-en-una-bucle-de-una-dataframe/94469#94469) con respecto al uso de `i` y `j`. ¿No será ese el problema?

Comment: @César parece que no, con la modificacion de `i` y `j` tengo     `mean_exp[i] = ema[-1] IndexError: list index out of range`. `ema` esta vacio porque nunca utilizamos la bucle interior.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Hubo un error, pongo los índices derechos en cuestión como se informó César.

Answer (score 1):

Te paso la función del cálculo de la media móvil exponencial que utiliza la librería de [LinkedIn Luminol](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol). La función de la media móvil exponencial está sacada de [aquí](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/blob/master/src/luminol/utils.py).

```
def compute_ema(smoothing_factor, points):
    """
    Compute exponential moving average of a list of points.
    :param float smoothing_factor: the smoothing factor.
    :param list points: the data points.
    :return list: all ema in a list.
    """
    ema = []
    # The initial point has a ema equal to itself.
    if(len(points) > 0):
        ema.append(points[0])
    for i in range(1, len(points)):
        ema.append(smoothing_factor * points[i] + (1 - smoothing_factor) * ema[i - 1])
    return ema
```

Funciona sencillamente pasando primero  el factor de suavizado y después los valores, ya sea una lista, un array de numpy o un pandas Series.